# How can I clone a public launchpad repository without login?

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I only want to clone some things, without changing them.

Is there any way to clone a repository without all the hassle of opening an account, setting up a SSH key, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really easy. Use `bzr branch lp:PROJECTNAME`.

Example (no Launchpad login or keys on this machine):

```
$ bzr branch lp:bzr
You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
```

and then it proceeds to download the code.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I had some misconfiguration issues because I tried that and did not work. Removing `~/.bazaar` helped.

Comment: Maybe you had an LP ssh key set up. The lp:project syntax expands to either an http or bar+ssh URL depending on if you have an LP login set up.

Comment: Almost. I had the login setup but not the ssh key, that was the mistake. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same, without having to install bzr?

Comment: @user10607 No, I think you will need bzr installed for sure. However you could use [git-bzr](https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng) to actually access it. You still need bzr to use the git-bzr.

Answer (score 1):

For those that can't or don't want to install Bazaar, we can download a tarball of a specific revision.

For example:

```
curl -sLo sakura.tar https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dabisu/sakura/sakura/tarball/621
```

Where the revision number is a change from https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dabisu/sakura/sakura/changes.

---

Or, maybe the project has the project source available for download from its project page:

```
curl -sLo sakura.tar.bz2 https://launchpad.net/sakura/trunk/3.7.1/+download/sakura-3.7.1.tar.bz2
```